# How do I run lots of subprocesses efficiently in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multicore

Basic setup:
I am using a python script for automatic testing of a programming project that I am working on. In the test, I run my executable with lots of different options and compare the result with previous runs. The testing takes quite a lot of time since I have roughly 600k different tests to run.

At the moment, I have split my script into two parts, a test-module that grabs tests from a job-queue and places results in a result-queue, and a main-module that creates the job-queue and then checks the results. This allows me to play around with using several test-processes/threads which so far has not given any improvement in testing speed (I am running this on a dual-core computer, I would expect more test-processes to work better on a quad-core).

In the test module, I create a command string that I then execute using

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I then read the results from the pipe and place it in the result-queue.

Question:

Is this the most efficient way of running lots and lots of command strings on a multi-core system? Every Popen I do creates a new process, which seems like it might create quite a bit of overhead, but I can't really think of a better way to do it.
(I am currently using python 2.7 in case this matters.)

EDIT:
OS is Linux
The subprocesses that I spawn are commandline C-executables with arguments.

Comment: are the commands other python programs?  command line programs?  Mixed bag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I created python C-bindings (with SWIG) directly to the code that I wanted to test. It turned out to be several hundred times faster than starting subprocesses.

Comment: +1. Avoiding starting processes at all is of course faster. It depends on how much control you have over your environment.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look to [mulitprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiproces#module-multiprocessing), especially the [Pool part](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiproces#using-a-pool-of-workers).

It will allow you to launch as processes as you want (default as many as CPU cores).

Comment: Already tried it without any performance gain unfortunately. The worker pool functionality was why I converted my test-script from AWK to python in the first place.

Comment: If you don't have any performance gain with processes pool, maybe it's because of your algorithm, if the jobs have to be done in a serialized way, no matter how you do parallelism, it won't gain anything.

Comment: The jobs are completely independent and can be done in parallell, the problem is that each job requires starting a subprocess which is probably what is killing performance.

Answer (score 1):

First, try measuring the testing script/scheme with a null-executable. That way you can see how much overhead the process spawning has w.r.t. actual testing time. Then we have some real data to act on.

Adding a batch mode to your exe (that reads command lines off a file and does that work) is probably a good idea if the amount of work is small compared to the time it takes to load and shut down your process. Plus, it will help you find memory leaks. :)

By moving stuff out of main(), this isn't so hard to do.

Comment: How does one create memory leaks in Python?

Comment: @tMC: One uses native libraries that leak, or keeps references around longer than intended, or defines __del__, which disables CPython's cyclic garbage collector.  The middle issue can be rather common, especially if your program is pasta-like. ;)

Comment: Good idea. Running the script with a "hello world"-executable took more or less the same time as performing my test. When I removed the subprocess calls however, the script completes in under 2 minutes, so it is definitely the subprocessing that kills performance.